# Titanium: How to create Label with Dynamic height?

Tags: objective-c, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

How to create a label with dynamic height in each row of a table view ?

Is there any way to calculate text size like in Objective C

```
CGSize mTempSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize] constrainedToSize:constrainedToSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

?

Thanks...

Comment: try to use this and see it works or not `your_element.size.height`.

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan: didn't get you..

Comment: Oh.. Actually i thought you need the height of the label after creation That solution will work if you get size of label after creation.

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan: no.. I want to set height dynamically to label based on the Text,say 3 lines, 4 lines

Comment: Did you try to set `height:auto`?

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan: yes I did but after label I have another label to put... so I could not fix 2nd label's top according to 1st label...

Answer (score -1):

i suppose [this](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/table_view_api_auto_height.js) is what you are looking for.

Cheers